# Can't open a temporary file for output using fstream

Tags: c++

I'm trying to create a temporary file to write data there, and then read them into an array.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    FILE* temp;
    temp = tmpfile();
    std::fputs("5\n1 2 3 4 5", temp);
    std::ifstream file = temp;
    //...open file for output in variable "myVar"...
    for (int i : myVar)
        std::cout << i << " ";
}
```

The problem is that I can't put the FILE type in the fstream object. Maybe there is some workaround to achieve my goal? I remind you that I need to create a temporary file, put the data there, and then read it (not a string) into an array.

Comment: Should `tmpfile` in this not be `std::tmpfile`?

Comment: If I understood the question correctly, then it seems that everything works without std::

Comment: There is a mix between C IO type (FILE*) and C++ (ifstream). Output file type for C++ is ofstream.

Comment: I'll try it, whatever that means :D